# Only single og:image is being shown

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

Here is the page I am having issue with:

https://www.bodystargym.com/members/gym/

So I have my Open-Graph tags defined, and the Facebook debugger is properly reading everything:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

However, the issue I am having is that my page has multiple og:image definitions, and only the first one is displaying (while the Raw Data on the debugger is picking up them all).

Any suggestions as to why only the first one, and not all 10, are showing up (when no errors are being thrown)?

Comment: What do you mean with just one being displayed? Where do you expect more than one do show?

Comment: @WizKid in the share dialog, it allows you to select which image will be used if you have multiple og:image definitions.